# Redirect from Zend Bootstrap?

Tags: php, zend-framework

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to redirect the browser from the bootstrap in Zend Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926361/is-there-a-way-to-redirect-the-browser-from-the-bootstrap-in-zend-framework)

I'm trying to redirect in the bootstrap file...

```
$this->_redirector->gotoUrl($url);
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function gotoUrl() on a non-object
```

How can I call gotoUrl() from the bootstrap?

Answer (score 4):

```
    $frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $response = new Zend_Controller_Response_Http();
    $response->setRedirect('/');
    $frontController->setResponse($response);
```